# Select row from table t1 where student stay together acording to date time and duration column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have  table t1 with 4 column and want to get row where Student stay two or more at a time

idea : add duration value of each student in date time then compare with up column date time

```
Student    date       time    Duration
   a       12-09-19 11:12:30    30
   b       12-09-19 11:13:30    60
   c       12-09-19 11:14:00    60
   d       12-09-19 11:18:30    40
```

results i want

```
Student    date       time   Duration
   b       12-09-19 11:13:30    60
   c       12-09-19 11:14:00    60
```

manually add duration in time then found b student 11:13:30  + 60 = 11:14:30 which is grater then student c date time so both b and c stay together 30 second

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, but this question needs to be reworked. There are a number of unknowns that make it impossible to answer. Is that an SQL table? The question is too broad too. Stack Overflow is not a place where you can dump your requirements and expect people to tell you where to start. You need to do an effort yourself first and show us what you have tried.

Comment: It’s probably better to put date end time into the same column in MySQL, of datatype `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Comment: I suppose that quite different solutions can be found in SQL and in Java. In SQL: I’d use `exists` in a query. In Java: I’d design a class for holding each row of the table, then probably let SQL sort by date and time and for neighbouring objects see if the overlap (end time of one is after start time of the following).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (Oracle; I don't speak MySQL).

Splitting date and time is a bad idea; those values should be contained in the same `DATE` datatype column (which is what I did; if your model really uses two columns, concatenate them first and then apply `TO_DATE` function).

What does this do?

- `T1` CTE is your sample data
- `INTER` adds `DURATION` number of seconds to each `DATUM` column value (`DATE` column name would be invalid, as far as Oracle is concerned, as it is reserved for datatype name)
- the final `SELECT` returns students whose `INTER.DATIME` values overlap

---

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with t1 (student, datum, duration) as
  2    (select 'a', to_date('12.09.2019 11:12:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 30 from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 'b', to_date('12.09.2019 11:13:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 60 from dual
  5     union all
  6     select 'c', to_date('12.09.2019 11:14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 60 from dual
  7     union all
  8     select 'd', to_date('12.09.2019 11:18:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 40 from dual
  9    ),
 10  inter as
 11    (select student, datum, duration,
 12            datum + (column_value - 1) / (24 * 60 * 60) datime
 13     from t1,
 14          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                              connect by level <= duration + 1
 16                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17    )
 18  select distinct student, datum, duration
 19  from inter
 20  where datime in (select datime
 21                   from inter
 22                   group by datime
 23                   having count(*) > 1);

S DATUM                 DURATION
- ------------------- ----------
b 12.09.2019 11:13:30         60
c 12.09.2019 11:14:00         60

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, spliting date and time is not a good idea in oracle. A simple solution would be to find all students that comes when another one is already there or visa/versa another one is already there when a student arrive.

Setup

```
alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss';

create table test (
Student  varchar2(31),
sdate    date,   
Duration number);

insert into test values  ('a','12-09-19 11:12:30',30);
insert into test values  ('b','12-09-19 11:13:30',60);
insert into test values  ('c','12-09-19 11:14:00',60);
insert into test values  ('d','12-09-19 11:18:30',40);
```

SQL

```
select * from test t 
where exists  (select 'x' from test where t.sdate between sdate and sdate + (duration / (24*60*60)) and t.student != student)
  or  exists  (select 'x' from test where sdate between t.sdate and t.sdate + (t.duration / (24*60*60)) and t.student != student);
```

Comment: `Thanks For Suggestion i am trying but already date as Timestamp and if  i am change its effect my7 other code  how i use timestamp for nls_Date_format   and duration as double  `                                 @F.Madsen                                           `ERROR: The '+' operator with a left operand type of 'TIMESTAMP' 
and a right operand type of 'DOUBLE' is not supported. Error 
Code: 30000 `

Comment: Not Found Any Solution we can add more column if we want but noting work

Comment: What do you mean by date as Timestamp ?

Comment: In my Table date have timestamp type

Comment: Ok but then I don't think you are testing in an Oracle DB. If not you should remove the Oracle tag from your question.